# Small angle approximation for coupled pendulum

Tags: coupled-oscillators

I am looking at a coupled plane pendulum problem where the pendula are identical with mass $m$ and length $r$, and connected by a spring with spring constant $k$ and an equilibrium seperation $d_0$. If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the angular displacement with the vertical then in these coordinates then the Lagrangian (I believe) is

$$L=\frac{1}{2}mr^2 \left( \dot{\theta_1^2} + \dot{\theta_2^2} \right) -mgr \left( \cos \theta_1 + \cos \theta_2 \right) -\frac{1}{2}k \left[ \sqrt{\left(r \sin \theta_1 - r \sin \theta_2 \right)^2 + \left(r \cos \theta_1 - r \cos \theta_2 \right)^2} -d_0\right]^2.$$

I'm trying to rewrite the approximate Lagrangian for small oscillations about the bottom in terms of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ where $\eta_{\alpha}$ represents the horizontal displacements. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Am I supposed to assume that $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$ is an equilibrium point and then expand the potential to second degree? In order to do this, can I assume that my $-mgr\left(\cos \theta_1 - \cos \theta_2 \right)$ can be approximated as

$$-mgr\left(\cos \theta_1 - \cos \theta_2 \right) \approx mgr\left(\frac{\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2}{2} \right)$$

and then for the spring terms write

$$\frac{1}{2}k \left[ \sqrt{\left(r \sin \theta_1 - r \sin \theta_2 \right)^2 + \left(r \cos \theta_1 - r \cos \theta_2 \right)^2} -d_0\right]^2=P(\theta_1, \theta_2)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}k \left[ \sqrt{\left(r \sin \theta_1 - r \sin \theta_2 \right)^2 + \left(r \cos \theta_1 - r \cos \theta_2 \right)^2} -d_0\right]^2 \approx \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial \theta_{\alpha} \partial \theta_{\beta}}\bigg|_{\theta_1=\theta_2=0} \theta_{\alpha} \theta_{\beta} $$

Then finally combine all like terms? Or before doing this can I simplify the root by writing $\sin \theta_{\alpha} = 0$ before doing the partial derivatives? I'm not sure which process is correct here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

If I write

$$V(\theta_1, \theta_2) = mgr \cos \theta_1 + mgr \cos \theta_2 + \frac{1}{2}k \left[ \sqrt{\left(r \sin \theta_1 - r \sin \theta_2 \right)^2 + \left(r \cos \theta_1 - r \cos \theta_2 \right)^2} -d_0\right]^2$$

then according to my calculations

$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \theta_1^2} = -\frac{1}{2}kr(2r-d)-mgr = \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \theta_2^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \theta_1 \partial \theta_2} = -\frac{1}{2}kr(2r-d_0)$$

Can I therefore write the Lagrangian as

$$L \approx \frac{1}{2}mr^2 \left( \dot{\theta_1^2} + \dot{\theta_2^2} \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{2}kr(2r-d_0) + mgr \right] \left(\theta_1^2 + \theta_2^2 \right)+\frac{1}{2}kr(2r-d_0) \theta_1 \theta_2$$

and then proceed to find the vibrational frequencies and normal modes using the K-M matrix procedure (after making the $\eta$ substitutions)? I'm wondering if there are any simplifications I can make to the potential (i.e. treat the approximation of the potential in multiple separate parts where I take derivatives of each individually) before I start taking partial derivatives to simplify the problem. Or does a multidimensional potential such as this always have to be treated as one massive beast?

Comment: For small angles, $\cos(x)\approx1$ and $\sin(x)\approx x$.

Comment: But about equilibrium the first derivative is irrelevant, and the lagrangian can be shifted by a constant, so doesn't that mean that I need $\cos x \approx -\frac{x^2}{2}$?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you, the small angle approximation *means* exactly what I wrote in the first comment. No derivatives are taken in its derivation, just application of a limit.

Comment: I have a Lagrangian T+V. I want to find normal modes and frequencies for small oscillations about equilibrium. Therefore, by analogy with the simple harmonic oscillator, in the potential shouldn't I treat $\cos(x)=1-V"(x) \frac{x^2}{2}$ since the 1 is a constant, and since it doesn't affect the motion of the Lagrangian the only term I need to keep is the second term. That is, if I'm understanding this procedure correctly.

Comment: (1) You are multiplying that 1 to $r$ which is certainly going to matter (2) how does the potential factor into the small angle approximation?